# cakephp3 giving undefined error for a defined variable

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-3.0

My Code is -

```
$user_id = 1;
$users = $this->UserModel->getUser($user_id);

$get_result = $this->Actionmodel->find('all', [
    'conditions' => ['id IN' => $ids],
    'contain' => [
        'Rank' => function ($q) {
            return $q
                ->select(['id', 'user_id', 'description'])
                ->where([
                    'status' => 1,
                    'user_id NOT IN' => $users
                ]);
        }
    ]
]);
```

giving error undefined users. while its printing user_id array.

Comment: Please keep in mind to format your code in a readable fashion before posting it here - thanks!

Comment: And indicating more specifically what the error is could be helpful. The code shown doesn't print anything, nor is the user_id variable an array.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `$users` in a closure without specifying it in `use`... do it like this:

```
$get_result = $this->Actionmodel->find('all',[
                                    'conditions'=>['id IN' => $ids],
                                    'contain'=>['Rank' => function ($q) use ($users) {
                                    return $q
                                    ->select(['id','user_id','description'])->where(['status' => 1,'user_id NOT IN' => $users]);}]]);
```